# Unable to upgrade compatibility level of existing database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I have an existing database and I need to update its  compatibility level from 120 to 130 or higher even after installing sql server 2019 (developer edition) and Sql Server Management Studio 2018 I am unable to upgrade compatibility level of my existing database.

Here is the screen shot of installed folder (C > Program Files > Microsoft Sql Server)
[image]

Installed directory showing list of all compatibility levels
[image]

But now showing in *database_name* > right click > properties > options > compatibility level (option to update  compatibility level) or with the query "ALTER DATABASE database_name
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL"

How can I update compatibility level with Sql Server 2016 (Installed)

Comment: Most likely the sql server, where your database resides, is not sql2019 one.

Comment: Did you restore the database onto the 2019 server?

Comment: not restored i need to updated existing database

Comment: @Arvo what's the resolution then ?

Comment: If the database is still on an old server you can't change its level until you move it to a new server. The old server doesn't know anything about the new one. It's unclear, from your description, where the database you want to upgrade is currently located

Comment: @ADyson its not server basically its a machine where i am working on ... database already created in the past and this older version not support some keywords i needed to implement so i want to update its compatibility level

Comment: Whether you have 2019 installed or not doesn't matter, it's if the instance the database is hosted on is 2019; clearly it's a 2014 instance.

Comment: @Larnu you got it right ... instance i am connected with showing (SQL Server 12.0.4100.1) which means its compatibility level is 120 i think ... so is there any way i can change compatibility level of this instance ...

Comment: You need to (presumably) purchase the licences and upgrade the instance.

Comment: `its not server`...yes it is... SQL Server is a database server. A server is a piece of software, not a machine.

Comment: You said you've installed a SQL Server 2019 instance somewhere. Have you tried backing up the database from the old 2014 instance, restoring it to the new 2019 instance and then upgrading its compatibility level there? In case it's not obvious - you can't go back from 2019 to 2014 again.

Comment: You can try to upgrade your existing sql server rather than installing a new one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that you are on the most current version of SQL Server Management Studio.  At the time of this posting is 19.0.1

We recently upgraded an instance to SQL 2019 and the installed version of Sql Server Management Studio(SSMS) was 17 (See attached image) which didn't show all the compatibility options.  Once we used a current version 19+ of SSMS all compatibility level options were available in the GUI.

Additionally, you should be able to verify the current database compatibility level with a SQL query and you are able to issue an ALTER database command with the appropriate compatibility level should you need to change it.  After issuing the compatibility level change simply verify the level is set properly.  If you were to double-check this in the GUI and it shows as BLANK this would confirm an outdated SSMS version is being used.

```
----  update database name to execute in the context of the database to verify ----
----  verify the current database compatibility level                    ----
 
USE [Database Name]

   select name, compatibility_level , version_name = 
    CASE compatibility_level
        WHEN 65  THEN 'SQL Server 6.5'
        WHEN 70  THEN 'SQL Server 7.0'
        WHEN 80  THEN 'SQL Server 2000'
        WHEN 90  THEN 'SQL Server 2005'
        WHEN 100 THEN 'SQL Server 2008/R2'
        WHEN 110 THEN 'SQL Server 2012'
        WHEN 120 THEN 'SQL Server 2014'
        WHEN 130 THEN 'SQL Server 2016'
        WHEN 140 THEN 'SQL Server 2017'
        WHEN 150 THEN 'SQL Server 2019'
        WHEN 160 THEN 'SQL Server 2022'
        ELSE 'not unknown - '+CONVERT(varchar(10),compatibility_level)
    END
    from sys.databases
    where name = db_name()

-----  update database name and compatibility level accordingly ----
-----  uncomment below after updating to issue change           ----
--  USE [master]
--  GO
--  ALTER DATABASE [Database Name] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
--  GO
```

[SQL Server Management Studio version difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcLwM.jpg)